# div:after fixed in parent scrollable container

Tags: css, css-position, fixed

I'm trying to position a semi-transparent gradient over a scrollable `<div>` container for visual effects with pure CSS. I want the gradient to stay in place, while the content below can be scrolled. The scrollbar has to be accessible, of course.

I tried using `:after` with position `absolute`, but this way the gradient is being scrolled as well. Using position `fixed` doesn't work either.

Side note: The content in the container is generated from a database. Actually, I wouldn't need the gradient if the content is less high than 100px, but that's a different task I think.

This is my code:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#eeeeee00, #eeeeeeff);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  Lorem<br><br> ipsum
  <br><br> dolor
  <br><br> sit
  <br><br> amet
  <br><br>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c6g89xm2/

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a trick using `position:sticky` that requires you to know the value of height:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  bottom:0;
  margin-top:-100px;
  height:100px;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, #eee);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  Lorem<br><br> ipsum
  <br><br> dolor
  <br><br> sit
  <br><br> amet
  <br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this clever approach. It suffers a bit from the fact that the size is fixed. But it is still sufficient for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a parent to the #container and use the :after on the parent? Like this:

```css
#container { 
  position: relative; 
  background: #fff;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#parent-container {
  position: relative;

}
#parent-container:after {
  content: ''; 
  display: block; 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 2; 
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  background: linear-gradient(#aaffff99, #ffaaff99); 
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-container">
  <div id="container">
  Lorem<br><br>
  ipsum<br><br>
  dolor<br><br>
  sit<br><br>
  amet<br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this. But then the gradient covers the scroll bar as well. As my gradient goes from transparent to opaque, the bottom of the scrollbar is invisible.